# Frame.__init__(self, window) vs. super().__init__()

Tags: user-interface, tkinter, constructor, frame

Is there any differences between the following two classes?

from tkinter import *

```
class MyFrame1(Frame):
    def __init__(self, window):
        super().__init__(window)
```

```
class MyFrame2(Frame):
    def __init__(self, window):
        Frame.__init__(self, window)
```

I think it is a matter of choice. Am I right?

Comment: FWIW, in your first example you're neglecting to pass `window` to the `__init__` method.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python super() vs Base.__init__ Method](https://thelearning.dev/python-super-vs-baseinit-method)

Comment: Thank you @Bryan for your comment. Actually, I did not get any error if not to pass `window`  to `__init__` method. I have revised the question.

Comment: Correct, you won't get an error. However, the widget will be created as a child of the root window instead of whatever widget you pass in.